# Get the text from a select option

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking to change an input field where a user write down a word. The word is then took to the javascript by using `document.getElementById("myInput1").value;`

So basically, in html it's this:

```
<input type="text" id="myInput1" placeholder="" style="z-index:1"></input>
<span onclick="newElement1()" class="addBtn" style="border-radius: 0px; height:30px">Add</span>
```

But know what i want is a select field, so the user won't be able to type something wrong or something that doesn't exist in a list:

```
  <select>
    <option value="0">Select car:</option>
    <option value="1">Audi</option>
    <option value="2">BMW</option>
    <option value="3">Citroen</option>
    <option value="4">Ford</option>
    <option value="5">Honda</option>
    <option value="6">Jaguar</option>
    <option value="7">Land Rover</option>
    <option value="8">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="9">Mini</option>
    <option value="10">Nissan</option>
    <option value="11">Toyota</option>
    <option value="12">Volvo</option>
  </select>
```

So without changing many things, I want to replace just in the html the input text by a selecting field. Then what the user will choose, it will have the id "myInput1" (and of course javascript knows what to do with this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to ask for the `value` of the `select` instead of the `input` field.

By the way setting `border-radius:0` is the same thing as not setting it at all and you can't set `height` on a `span` (unless you change the `span` to `display:block` or `display:inline-block`) because `span` elements are inline elements and their `height` is determined by their content.

```js
// If an element has an id, then .getElementById() is the most direct way
// to access it.
let make = document.getElementById("carMake");

// If an element doesn't have an id, .querySelector() is very easy to use
// to get a reference to the element. Here, the selector is for the .addBtn class
document.querySelector(".addBtn").addEventListener("click", function(){
  // Get the text of the selected <option>
  console.log("You selected: ", carMake.options[carMake.selectedIndex].textContent);
  
  // Get the value of the selected <option>
  console.log("You selection has a value of: ", carMake.value);  
});
```

```html
<span class="addBtn">Add</span>

  <select id="carMake">
    <option value="0">Select car:</option>
    <option value="1">Audi</option>
    <option value="2">BMW</option>
    <option value="3">Citroen</option>
    <option value="4">Ford</option>
    <option value="5">Honda</option>
    <option value="6">Jaguar</option>
    <option value="7">Land Rover</option>
    <option value="8">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="9">Mini</option>
    <option value="10">Nissan</option>
    <option value="11">Toyota</option>
    <option value="12">Volvo</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: So will it work with a getElementbyValue ? (I don't even know if this exists i'm new to this by the way).

Comment: @LiquidSnake There is no such thing as `.getElementbyValue`. You get the value of a form field element by accessing its `.value` property. You get the content of a non-form field with either `.textContent` or `.innerHTML` (depending on whether the content contains HTML or not).

Comment: So then, should I change `document.getElementById("myInput1").value;` by `document.querySelector("select").value);`

Comment: @LiquidSnake There are many ways to reference an element... `.getElementById()` and `.querySelector()` are very common. Whatever method you use, you would then just get the `.value`. In my example, I'm getting the `select` reference by `.getElementById()` and the `add` button by `.querySelector()`.

Comment: Alternaly, is it possible to give an id to each car in the selecting field and then do a `.getElementById()` to get that value selected ?

Comment: @LiquidSnake That won't work because, although each `option` would have an `id`, you wouldn't know which one was selected. The way I'm showing you is the way to do it. I'm not sure why you are looking for alternatives. This is pretty straight-forward.

Comment: I'll try what you said then and use `querySelector("select").value);`

Comment: I tried it and it worked, but the problem is that i want to print not the value but the name of the car. When I select Audi it gives back the number 1, but I want the string Audi, how can i do it ?

Comment: @LiquidSnake Please look carefully at my answer and click the "Run code snippet" button to see that I have already provided you with the code that gets the `value` of the selected `option` as well as code for how to get the text of the selected `option`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    <span class="addBtn" onclick="newElement1()">Add</span>

          <select id="carMake">
            <option value="0">Select car:</option>
            <option value="1">Audi</option>
            <option value="2">BMW</option>
            <option value="3">Citroen</option>
            <option value="4">Ford</option>
            <option value="5">Honda</option>
            <option value="6">Jaguar</option>
            <option value="7">Land Rover</option>
            <option value="8">Mercedes</option>
            <option value="9">Mini</option>
            <option value="10">Nissan</option>
            <option value="11">Toyota</option>
            <option value="12">Volvo</option>
          </select>
 <script>
       function newElement1() {
        var e= document.getElementById("carMake");
        var value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        $('#myInput1').val(value);  }
</script>
```